# MySQL error #1064 while creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS brandRep $$
CREATE TRIGGER brandRep AFTER UPDATE ON sales_flat_order
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.status <> OLD.status AND OLD.applied_rule_ids <=> 45182) THEN
    UPDATE reps_transaction_history_ids
    SET order_status = NEW.status 
    WHERE order_id = OLD.increment_id;
ENDIF $$

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Is `<=>` really an operator in MySQL? What does it mean?

Comment: It's a [null-safe equality comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) apparently. @Hoze The text of the error message might be useful.

Comment: error message :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems

**PROBLEM #1** : `ENDIF` is wrong. It's `END IF`

**PROBLEM #2** : `END IF $$` is wrong. It's `END IF;`

This is how it should appear

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS brandRep $$
CREATE TRIGGER brandRep AFTER UPDATE ON sales_flat_order
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.status <> OLD.status AND OLD.applied_rule_ids <=> 45182) THEN
    UPDATE reps_transaction_history_ids
    SET order_status = NEW.status 
    WHERE order_id = OLD.increment_id;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**